# Query on Collections.unmodifiableList() behaviour

Tags: java, collections

I have a query regarding `unmodifiableList` API of `Collections`.

Code snippet:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReadOnlyList{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Stack");
        list.add("Over");
        List list1 = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
        //list1.add("Flow");
        list.add("Flow");
        System.out.println("sizes:1:2:"+list.size()+":"+list1.size());
        for (Iterator it = list1.iterator();it.hasNext();){
            System.out.println("elements:"+it.next());
        }
        System.out.println("__________");
        list.remove("Flow");
        for (Iterator it = list1.iterator();it.hasNext();){
            System.out.println("elements:"+it.next());
        }       
    }
}
```

I know that I can't modify the unmodifible collection and hence I will get error for

```
//list1.add("Flow");
```

I expected that I will get read-only list of `list` varaible until the point I create `unmodifiableList`. But even after this `list1` creation, the changes in parent list are reflected in child `list1`

I can't modify child unmodifible list but still I receive modifications of parent list. It's a surprise for me.

I know that fix is creating new Collection from parent but stil did not understand above behaviour.

Comment: `Collections.unmodifiableList(list);` will create a wrapper around `list` that throws exceptions in all modifying methods and delegates all reading methods to the list itself. Hence changes made to `list` will be reflected in `list1`. I guess you want to create a copy, e.g. `Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(list))` (i.e. you create a copy of list and wrap that with the unmodifiable wrapper).

Comment: It shouldn't be a surprise, the documentation states that this is just a view of the original collection. This is why we always make defensive **copies** whenever the source of the data is outside our control. Unmodifiable **views** are only useful in the reverse case: when you control the original data source (the underlying collection) and you want to expose it to someone without allowing them to mess with your original list.

Comment: "but stil did not understand above behaviour" - what is it that you don't understand about this behavior? As biziclop mentioned the Javadoc clearly specifies the the method returns a view on the internal list that cannot be modified through that view but it never says anything about the original list.

Comment: I am clear now. I have expcted read only copy of parent till that time and parent modificaitons are not reflected in child.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Collections` JavaDoc explains this clearly:

> Returns an unmodifiable **view** of the specified list. This method allows
>   modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal lists.
>   Query operations on the returned list "read through" to the specified
>   list, and attempts to modify the returned list, whether direct or via
>   its iterator, result in an UnsupportedOperationException.

(I emboldened "view")

So when you do:

```
 List<Foo> unmodifiable = Collections.unmodifiableList(existingList);
```

... you cannot modify the list by calling `unmodifiable.add(...)` etc.  But any changes caused by calls to `existingList.add(...)` will be visible through `unmodifiable.get(...)`, `unmodifiable.size()` etc.

As the Javadoc says, this means you can give another object a read-only view of a list that your class will continue to modify:

```
class ContactManager {

   List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();        

    public List<Contact> contacts() {
        return Collection.unmodifiableList(contacts);
    }

    public void addContact(String name) {
       contacts.add(new Contact(name));
    }
}
```

Now another class:

- can call `contacts()` and get a List they can browse
- can call `addContact()` to add an entry to the list
- can see the new contact in their view of the list
- **cannot** avoid using `addContact()` by instead calling `list.add(new Contact(...))`

This could be dangerous in a multi-threaded program. For example, if in one thread, a class works with the unmodifiable view:

```
 List<contacts> contactsView = contactManager.contacts();
 int lastEntry = contactsView.size() - 1;
 contactsView.get(lastEntry);
```

... while in another thread, the ContactManager modifies the list:

```
 contacts.remove(0);
```

... then if the timing is just-so, the first routine will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because the list has shrunk between querying the length and trying to read the last entry.

---

If you want to initialise a list then ensure you don't make further changes to it, you can achieve that by restricting the scope of the variable pointing to the modifiable list:

```
 private List<String> validResponses() {
       List<String> responses = new ArrayList<>();
       values.add("Yes");
       values.add("Agree")
       values.add("No");
       values.add("Disagree");
       return Collections.unmodifiableList(responses);
 }
```

The scope of `responses` is just this method. Nothing outside the method can reach `responses`, and so nothing outside this method can modify the list.

This is generally a good idea, if you choose to adopt the practice of using immutable objects wherever possible.

---

If you have a list whose contents are going to be changing, but you want callers to get an unchanging list, you need to make a *defensive copy* of the list.

```
public List<Contact> contacts() {
     List<Contact> copy = new ArrayList<>();
     List.copy(contacts, copy);
     return Collections.unmodifiableMap(copy);
}
```

(In this case, we didn't need to make the returned list unmodifiable to protect ourselves, but it's helpful to the caller -- if they call `add()` or `set()` they'll get an exception, instead of a success that doesn't actually update the "real" list.

---

There are libraries that can help with this kind of thing, for example Guava has some more fluent APIs for initialising immutable lists, either from scratch or as defensive copies of existing lists.

Comment: In the last case it is also an option to directly create an immutable copy of the original list, i.e. with Guava's `ImmutableList`.

Comment: @biziclop I wanted to stay away from libraries, but Guava is worth mentioning so I added a paragraph.

Comment: Although from your answer it seems Collections.unmodifiableList returns VIEW of same object rather than creating a new object on heap with unmodifible restrictions. I am just confirming is my understand is right? No NEW OBJECT WILL BE CREATED ON HEAP RIGHT

Comment: @UmarTahir A very small new object will be created on the heap, which implements that view of the existing object. You can look at the source for that class: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java